# C++ fscanf() returns -1 and doesn't overwrite variable

Tags: c++, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to make a program in C++ that reads `version` from `File.txt` and outputs if the number is correct (`CORRECT VERSION` or `INCORRECT VERSION`). I'm using Eclipse on a Mac.

Below you can see my program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  FILE *pFile;
  pFile = fopen("./Desktop/File.txt", "a+");
  int version = 0, result = 0;
  int *pointer = &version;
  result = fscanf(pFile, "%d", pointer);
  if (version == 1)
    fprintf(pFile, "CORRECT VERSION");
  else
    fprintf(pFile, "INCORRECT VERSION - %d, %d", version, result);
  fclose(pFile);
  
  return 0;
}
```

`File.txt` before...

```
1
```

and after...

```
1INCORRECT VERSION - 0, -1
```

I've searched around the internet and stackoverflow.com and I found some other discussions ([fscanf() filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295121/fscanf-filter), [Stopping fscanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985406/stopping-fscanf), [fscanf csv in C. Value not assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208976/fscanf-csv-in-c-value-not-assigned)). I tried all of them, but none of them worked. Any help is appreciated. (By the way, this is my first post.)

Adam

## EDIT:

@FrankPuffer I tried replacing `a+` with `r+` in `line 5` and it works even though I have no idea why, because I'm pretty sure that the only difference between `a+` and `r+` are:

- If the file doesn't exist `a+` creates it and `r+` returns an error
- If you output into a file `a+` writes at the end and `r+` replaces the whole file

Comment: Why do you use `fscanf` at all? Why not `std::ifstream`?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Never used it myself, but according to documentation, "a+" is for both append and read. However I would try "r" or "r+" instead.

Comment: Is this the code that you are using i.e. `int version = 0, resul = 0;` is missing a `t` for a good result

Comment: And does the file exist relative to running the program. Perhaps check for NULL from `fopen`

Comment: @EdHeal This is the code I'm using, except the `resul`

Comment: where does v declared ? is this program compile-able ?

Comment: @DUJiaen `v` -> `version`, yes it's compile-able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), scanf returns

> the number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if
>   read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

In your example it returns -1 (EOF in most environments) so it doesn't change the value of version (`0`) and that explains the "incorrect" print. I couldn't reproduce that output with a file containing a single `1` (it seems your case) or a `1` followed by a newline, but to make your program "work" in any case I added this line:

```
fseek(pFile,0,SEEK_END);
```

before the final if statement

```
if (version == 1)
```

BTW if the `C++` tag wasn't wrong (and you did actually include `<iostream>`) you should use streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::cerr;

const int version_needed = 1;

int main() {

    std::fstream file{"File.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out };   
    if ( file.bad() ) {
        cerr << "Sorry, can't open file.\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    int version;
    file >> version;
    if ( file.fail() ) {
        cerr << "Error: can't read an int from file.\n"
             << "Unable to retrieve version number.\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    // set state bit to good, you may have reach EOF while reading, but now
    // you want to write on the file
    file.clear();
    // set output position to the end of file. It should be there, anyway
    file.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
    if ( version == version_needed )
        file << "CORRECT VERSION";
    else
        file << "INCORRECT VERSION - " << version << " instead of " << version_needed;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`

`FWIW, this worked for me:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <system_error>

int main() {
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("/tmp/file.txt", "a+");
    if (!pFile) {
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category());
    }
    int version = 0;
    int result;
    result = fscanf(pFile, "%d", &version);
    if (!result) {
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category());
    }
    if (version == 1)
        fprintf(pFile, "CORRECT VERSION");
    else
        fprintf(pFile, "INCORRECT VERSION - %d, %d", version, result);
    fclose(pFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `!result` be `result != 1`

Comment: @EdHeal: Yes, checking for the exact nr of matched args is probably better.

Comment: This is pretty much the same program as my. I don't see a difference? You also declared `result` twice on `line 10-11`

Comment: @AdamSvestka Someone might have edited my code, I never declare 2 variables on the same line, especially important since I prefer the object oriented declaration style 'SomeClass* ptr; My code checks for errors, yours does not.